# Why displaying different page instead of set as startup page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I started to work in a new project developed in asp.net. In this application authencation used is forms authentication and session timeout is 10 min. Also IIS used is IIS expression for development purpose.

Issue is that even if I set login.aspx as the startup page for the first time it goes always first to pagenotfound.aspx page. But in 2nd attempte it display this page correctly. Also if I click on any other page even 2 minutes keeping system idle it again display pagenotfound.aspx page but in 2nd attempt display page correctly. pagenotfound is the page which is created to display if user do any invalid request but unable to find the reason while it always goes to that page instead of startup or requested page

Comment: what does the code look like?

Comment: try setting startup project

Comment: Please review use of XPages tag by hovering on it. I don't think that tag is applicable for this question.

Comment: Hi had already set the startup project. It is showing different page in same project

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url always shows pagenotfound.aspx for first time

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in web config

```
<system.webServer>  
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="index.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

for forms authentcation  use below code

```
 <system.web>
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/index.aspx" defaultUrl="~/index.aspx"/>
  </authentication>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: This code is already there and point to login.aspx page. Surprisingly if I choose windows authentication instead of forms it works well but if forms autentication than it display that page

Comment: The above code not depend upon any form or windows authentication. For formauthentication use below code                                         <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/index.aspx" defaultUrl="~/index.aspx"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: Used following code but still facing the issue :- 
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Pages/Home.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Pages/Home.aspx"/>
      </authentication>